# Banshee Errors while loading

Tags: banshee

I got the following log trace when starting Banshee on Ubuntu 18.04, I don't know when this started to crash, even after re-install ... Can anyone help me ?

```
    [Warn  11:21:47.636] DBus support could not be started. Disabling for this session. - System.MethodAccessException: Method `DBus.BusObject..ctor()' is inaccessible from method `org.freedesktop.DBus.IBusProxy..ctor()' (in `')
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_throw_method_access(intptr,intptr)
  at org.freedesktop.DBus.IBusProxy..ctor () [0x00000] in <960ba2a114bb43e39b965094aead9203>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (in `mscorlib')
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x0001a] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00095] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache) [0x00009] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00027] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00020] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at DBus.BusObject.GetObject (DBus.Connection conn, System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath object_path, System.Type declType) [0x0000d] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Connection.GetObject (System.Type type, System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath path) [0x00018] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Connection.GetObject[T] (System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath path) [0x00001] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus..ctor (System.String address) [0x0000f] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x0002b] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_System () [0x00035] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
System.Exception: Unable to open the system message bus. (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.get_System () [0x00052] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.BusG.Init () [0x00010] in <b1f3e777b0f64162a9da78c440c424af>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.Connect (System.String serviceName, System.Boolean init) [0x0000e] in <1db85bdd7591446c8843ac8d643695aa>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.GrabDefaultName () [0x00018] in <1db85bdd7591446c8843ac8d643695aa>:0 
[Info  11:21:47.649] Running Banshee 2.6.2: [Ubuntu Artful Aardvark (development branch) (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2017-08-12 03:07:49 UTC]
[Warn  11:21:48.100] No se puede conectar con NetworkManager o Wicd - Se asumirá una conexión disponible y en funcionamiento
[Warn  11:21:48.722] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <ed39f21b9e9343dcbd442a17ad356a9f>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
[Warn  11:21:48.770] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <ed39f21b9e9343dcbd442a17ad356a9f>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
[Warn  11:21:48.788] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <ed39f21b9e9343dcbd442a17ad356a9f>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
[Warn  11:21:48.795] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <ed39f21b9e9343dcbd442a17ad356a9f>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
[Warn  11:21:48.805] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <ed39f21b9e9343dcbd442a17ad356a9f>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
[Info  11:21:49.001] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Warn  11:21:49.044] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x000c5] in <cf7a7ec1674f48dd88ab56caf61068fa>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x0003b] in <1db85bdd7591446c8843ac8d643695aa>:0 
[Warn  11:21:49.044] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Warn  11:21:49.073] Failed to load media-player-info file for 1
[Warn  11:21:49.106] Failed to load media-player-info file for 1
[Warn  11:21:49.128] Caught an exception - System.MethodAccessException: Method `DBus.BusObject..ctor()' is inaccessible from method `org.freedesktop.DBus.IBusProxy..ctor()' (in `')
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_throw_method_access(intptr,intptr)
  at org.freedesktop.DBus.IBusProxy..ctor () [0x00000] in <960ba2a114bb43e39b965094aead9203>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (in `mscorlib')
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x0001a] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00095] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache) [0x00009] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00027] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00020] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at DBus.BusObject.GetObject (DBus.Connection conn, System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath object_path, System.Type declType) [0x0000d] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Connection.GetObject (System.Type type, System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath path) [0x00018] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Connection.GetObject[T] (System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath path) [0x00001] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus..ctor (System.String address) [0x0000f] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x0002b] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00035] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
[Warn  11:21:49.128] Extension `Banshee.SoundMenu.SoundMenuService' not started: Unable to open the session message bus.
[Warn  11:21:49.196] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x000c5] in <cf7a7ec1674f48dd88ab56caf61068fa>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x0003b] in <1db85bdd7591446c8843ac8d643695aa>:0 
[Warn  11:21:49.196] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Warn  11:21:49.198] Caught an exception - System.MethodAccessException: Method `DBus.BusObject..ctor()' is inaccessible from method `org.freedesktop.DBus.IBusProxy..ctor()' (in `')
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_throw_method_access(intptr,intptr)
  at org.freedesktop.DBus.IBusProxy..ctor () [0x00000] in <960ba2a114bb43e39b965094aead9203>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (in `mscorlib')
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x0001a] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00095] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache) [0x00009] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00027] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00020] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
  at DBus.BusObject.GetObject (DBus.Connection conn, System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath object_path, System.Type declType) [0x0000d] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Connection.GetObject (System.Type type, System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath path) [0x00018] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Connection.GetObject[T] (System.String bus_name, DBus.ObjectPath path) [0x00001] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus..ctor (System.String address) [0x0000f] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x0002b] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00035] in <a8017a4309ba4def9cf38b60b9629c38>:0 
[Warn  11:21:49.199] Extension `Banshee.SoundMenu.SoundMenuService' not started: Unable to open the session message bus.
[Info  11:21:49.201] All services are started 1,238884

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x55bf818b9265 - banshee : (null)
    0x55bf818b95fc - banshee : (null)
    0x55bf81864a21 - banshee : (null)
    0x55bf818b2bfb - banshee : (null)
    0x7f0c1b732d93 - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 : (null)
    0x55bf81b122f8 - banshee : (null)

=================================================================
    Telemetry Dumper:
=================================================================
Pkilling 0x7f0bf8a25700 from 0x7f0c26a63780
Pkilling 0x7f0c24af8700 from 0x7f0c26a63780
Pkilling 0x7f0c102b0700 from 0x7f0c26a63780
Pkilling 0x7f0bf8c26700 from 0x7f0c26a63780
Pkilling 0x7f0bf8824700 from 0x7f0c26a63780
Could not exec mono-hang-watchdog, expected on path '/etc/../bin/mono-hang-watchdog' (errno 2)
Entering thread summarizer pause from 0x7f0c26a63780
Finished thread summarizer pause from 0x7f0c26a63780.

Waiting for dumping threads to resume

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7f0c1b732d93):0x7f0c1b732d83  54 49 89 f5 55 53 48 89 fd 48 83 ec 08 48 8b 1e  TI..USH..H...H..
0x7f0c1b732d93  48 8b 33 48 85 f6 74 09 48 8b 7f 08 e8 4c 91 ff  H.3H..t.H....L..
0x7f0c1b732da3  ff 48 39 5d 18 48 8b 7d 00 0f 84 be 00 00 00 48  .H9].H.}.......H
0x7f0c1b732db3  39 5d 10 0f 84 ca 00 00 00 4c 89 ee 4c 8d 63 10  9].......L..L.c.

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at KeyFile.GKeyFile:g_key_file_free <0x000a2>
      at FinalizerInfo:Handler <0x0002f>
      at TimeoutProxy:Invoke <0x00032>
      at GLib.SourceProxy:HandlerInternal <0x00044>
      at GLib.SourceProxy:HandlerInternal <0x0007a>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at Gtk.Application:gtk_main <0x0009f>
      at Gtk.Application:Run <0x00023>
      at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient:Run <0x000d3>
      at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient:Startup <0x00072>
      at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup:Startup <0x000e8>
      at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient:Startup <0x000f7>
      at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient:Startup <0x0016b>
      at Nereid.Client:Main <0x00033>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object <0x00091>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at System.AppDomain:ExecuteAssembly <0x000b7>
      at System.AppDomain:ExecuteAssemblyInternal <0x0005c>
      at System.AppDomain:ExecuteAssembly <0x0004a>
      at System.AppDomain:ExecuteAssembly <0x000ca>
      at System.AppDomain:ExecuteAssembly <0x00039>
      at System.AppDomain:ExecuteAssembly <0x000a2>
      at Booter.Booter:BootClient <0x000ca>
      at Booter.Booter:Main <0x00257>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_void <0x00086>
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Banshee has been abandoned by its developers.

Because of its dependency upon an old version of Mono, Banshee no longer functions properly.

Manjaro and Arch Linux users have been trying to make it work, without much success.

I have an old netbook running wattOS 10 (16.04) purely so I can run Banshee.

Alternatively, one could either install 16.04 to a separate partition, or run it in a virtual machine or emulator. The Windows version does not work in WINE.

That's the best advice I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Banshee haven't released a stable version since Feb 2014 (2.6.2), and it seems to be abandoned. I switched from Banshee to Rhythmbox several years ago because changing album covers in Banshee was too difficult and time-consuming. Clementine is an alternative to Banshee in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Clementine ( `sudo apt install clementine` ) is a music player focusing on a fast and easy-to-use interface for searching and playing your music.

Summary of included features:

- Search and play your local music library.
- Listen to internet radio from SomaFM, Magnatune, Jamendo, Intergalactic FM,
  Digitally Imported, JAZZRADIO.com, ROCKRADIO.com, RadioTunes.com,
  Soundcloud, Icecast and Subsonic servers.
- Search and play songs you've uploaded to Box, Dropbox, Google Drive, and OneDrive.
- Create smart playlists and dynamic playlists.
- Tabbed playlists, import and export M3U, XSPF, PLS and ASX
- CUE sheet support
- Play audio CDs.
- Visualizations from projectM
- Lyrics and artist biographies and photos
- Transcode music into MP3, Ogg Vorbis, Ogg Speex, FLAC or AAC.
- Edit tags on MP3 and OGG files, organize your music.
- Fetch missing tags from MusicBrainz.
- Discover and download Podcasts.
- Download missing album cover art from Last.fm.
- Native desktop notifications using libnotify
- Remote control using an Android device, a Wii Remote, MPRIS or the command-line
- Copy music to your iPod, iPhone, MTP or mass-storage USB player.
- Queue manager

Answer (score 0):

Banshee needs a few changes on Ubuntu 22.04 to run from script1.sh:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
PROXY=""
MONO_PREFIX=/usr/lib/mono
GNOME_PREFIX=/opt/gnome
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib
export PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/bin:$PATH:/usr/lib/banshee/:/usr/lib
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket
MONO_ZERO_LEN_ARRAY=""
MDB_DEBUG_FLAGS=logfile
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug

LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so banshee --uninstalled --debug-addins --debug
```

> and changing the line in /usr/bin/banshee :

```
exec_args="-a $BANSHEE_EXEC_NAME  mono $MONO_OPTIONS $MONO_EXE $BANSHEE_DEBUG $BANSHEE_CLIENT"
```

to:

exec_args=" mono $MONO_OPTIONS $MONO_EXE $BANSHEE_DEBUG $BANSHEE_CLIENT"